# angular-eonasdan-datetimepicker option paramter not taking in the defined format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

```
<div class="input-group" datetimepicker ng-model="patient.dob" options="patient.options">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" name="time" ng-blur="ageCalc()">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

This is my angular code for date-time-picker. My `options="patient.options"` does not take the format for date as I have defined . Please help me resolve the issue.

```
var patient = this;
patient.dob = moment();
patient.options = {format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'};
```

This is the script that I have added for options, but it is not taking the format. I have also added the required script files required. My output is displayed in the default `format :'YY/MM/DD HH:mm'` but I want in the above mentioned format.

Reference link: [Referred Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/n8L8UZ?p=preview)